# How to list all builds of a given project through Travis API?

Tags: api, travis-ci

The Travis documentation is not clear if we can navigate through the builds. The endpoint:

https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/caelum/vraptor4/builds

Shows the last 50 builds.

But how to get the whole history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Builds are paginated, so you need to fetch with multiple requests.

The endpoint supports the `after_number` parameter, which is the build number (field `number`) from the last build in the previously fetched page.

So if your first result set's last build entry has the build number 2669 (which is the current last build number on the page from https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/caelum/vraptor4/builds), you'd fetch subsequent builds with this URL:

`https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/caelum/vraptor4/builds?after_number=2669`

That way you iterate through the builds rather than fetch thousands of them at once.

Comment: Shouldn't after_number be before_number? It seems that the list are going backwarding.

Answer (score 0):

For API V3, we should use `offset` instead, see https://developer.travis-ci.com/pagination

For example, `https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/expertiza%2Fexpertiza/builds?limit=5&offset=5`